# removing columns in R matrix using column names - independent of order

Tags: r, matrix

I am having trouble with removing columns in a matrix using column names - the output is dependent on the order of the column names.

```
matrix <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), 3,4,dimnames = list(c("R1","R2","R3"), c("C1","C2","C3","C4")))

setA <- c("C2","C3")
setB <- c("C3","C2")

matrixA <- matrix[, colnames(matrix)!=setA]
matrixB <- matrix[, colnames(matrix)!=setB]
```

i was expecting the output the same in the both cases (expected output is output of matrixB)

however, the actual output i got was:

```
> matrixA
   C1 C2 C3 C4
R1  1  4  7 10
R2  2  5  8 11
R3  3  6  9 12
> matrixB
   C1 C4
R1  1 10
R2  2 11
R3  3 12
```

In my actual problem, i wil have to choose the elements of setA in a random order. How do i make sure that the columns are actually removed?

Comment: try `matrix[, !colnames(matrix) %in% setA]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the elements of `setA` and `setB` are *recyecled* to have the same length as `colnames(matrix)`.

`setA` will become `c("C2", "C3", "C2", "C3")` when used in `colnames(matrix)!=setA`. Likewise, `setB` will become `c("C3", "C2", "C3", "C2")` when used in `colnames(matrix)!=setB`.  That is why all columns are selected for `setA` and only 2 columns are selected for `setB`.

```
colnames(matrix)
[1] "C1" "C2" "C3" "C4"

colnames(matrix)!=setA
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

colnames(matrix)!=setB
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

You can use the following to omit the  columns you don't want.

```
!colnames(matrix) %in% setB
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
matrix[,!colnames(matrix)%in%YOURSET]
```

```
> identical(matrix[,!colnames(matrix)%in%setA],
            matrix[,!colnames(matrix)%in%setB])

[1] TRUE
```